# Infinitely expanding queue in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, queue, breadth-first-search

Last night I was attempting to solve leetcode's [Number of Islands](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/) challenge. I was quite pleased with myself for solving it so quickly. The solution iterates over the rows of the grid until it finds a cell with land. Then the program enters a function to find all contiguous cells with land (BFS), replace them with water, and then return. Island count is incremented, and this repeats until all cells are converted to water.

Easy right? However the program stalls on the following testcase:

```
import queue
grid = [
    ["1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","0"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","0","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","0"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","0"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]
]

def print_grid(grid):
    for idxr, row in enumerate(grid):
        for idxc, cell in enumerate(row):
            print(f"[{grid[idxr][idxc]}]", end="")
        print("")

    print("\n----\n")

def nuke_island(grid, idxr, idxc):
    """Traverses and destroys an island."""
    # Create a queue of our first cell
    island_cells = queue.Queue()
    island_cells.put((idxr, idxc))

    # Process our queue
    while not island_cells.empty():
        # Retrieve a new cell from queue
        idxr, idxc = island_cells.get()

        # Replace new cell with water
        grid[idxr][idxc] = "0"

        #Try to add all valid connecting cells to the queue
        for row, col in [(idxr-1, idxc), (idxr+1, idxc), (idxr, idxc-1), (idxr, idxc+1)]:
            # Don't allow python to backwards-index
            if row < 0 or col < 0:
                continue
            try:
                # Retieve the connecting cell
                cell = grid[row][col]

                # If the cell is land, add it to the queue
                if cell == "1":
                    island_cells.put((row, col))

            except IndexError:
                # We went off the map, continue
                continue

    # We've processed all connecting cells and nuked the whole island, return updated grid
    return grid

# Set number of islands to zero
islands = 0

# Iterate through the grid
for idxr, row in enumerate(grid):
    for idxc, cell in enumerate(row):
        # If our cell is land, enter nuke_island
        if cell == '1':
            grid = nuke_island(grid, idxr, idxc)
            islands += 1

# Return the number of total islands
print(f"Islands: {islands}")
```

If you look at the above example you can see that the grid only has one island. **The program starts at cell [0][0], enters the nuke_island() subroutine, and gets stuck there.** If you use the print_grid() debugging function you can see that the program removes land cells as expected until a certain point, then stops. The problem is the queue 'island_cells'.

**For some reason the queue is continuing to grow faster than items are being removed and continues to grow forever.** I have no idea why since this doesn't occur with previous testcases, even previous testcases with only one island. **If I replace the queue with a list in the code:**

```
grid = [
    ["1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","0"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","0","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","0","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","0"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","0"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]
]

def print_grid(grid):
    for idxr, row in enumerate(grid):
        for idxc, cell in enumerate(row):
            print(f"[{grid[idxr][idxc]}]", end="")
        print("")

    print("\n----\n")

def nuke_island(grid, idxr, idxc):
    """Traverses and destroys an island."""
    # Create a list of our first cell
    island_cells = [(idxr, idxc)]

    # Process our list
    while len(island_cells) > 0:
        # Retrieve a new cell from queue
        (idxr, idxc) = island_cells.pop()

        # Replace new cell with water
        grid[idxr][idxc] = "0"

        # Try to add all valid connecting cells to the queue
        for (row, col) in [(idxr-1, idxc), (idxr+1, idxc), (idxr, idxc-1), (idxr, idxc+1)]:
            # Don't allow python to backwards-index
            if row < 0 or col < 0:
                continue
            try:
                # Retieve the connecting cell
                cell = grid[row][col]

                # If the cell is land, add it to the queue
                if cell == "1":
                    island_cells.append((row, col))

            except IndexError:
                # We went off the map, continue
                continue

    # We've processed all connecting cells and nuked the whole island, return updated grid
    return grid

# Set number of islands to zero
islands = 0

# Iterate through the grid
for idxr, row in enumerate(grid):
    for idxc, cell in enumerate(row):
        # If our cell is land, enter nuke_island
        if cell == '1':
            grid = nuke_island(grid, idxr, idxc)
            islands += 1

# Return the number of total islands
print(f"Islands: {islands}")
```

The program now works as expected. **Even though I am using the list interchangeably with a FIFO queue**. So what is going on? Why does the queue grow infinitely? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: append(...) / pop() is actually LIFO not FIFO so you've switched to DFS

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that! I came here to update the question. Still, why does using BFS hang forever and seem to keep adding items to the queue? There are only 400 cells.

Comment: probably you never dedupe -- you'd need to debug it (which is off topic for stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong. As Anthony helpfully pointed out, due to not using list.pop(0), I was actually using LIFO (DFS) instead of FIFO (BFS). When I switched to a LifoQueue() the program worked as expected.

Secondly, I didn't check to see if neighbors were already in the queue, and thus I added duplicate entries. Making the check resolved the issue.